# Opencart Smtp mail sending is not working on localhost

Tags: opencart

I tried many changes but not working mail sending function. I changed settings - mail tab and add SMTP credentials and also changed my xampp configuration settings (php.ini and sendmail.ini). Still didn't work.

```
Opencart mail settings:
Mail Engine: SMTP
Mail Parameters: blank
SMTP Hostname: ssl://smtp.gmail.com (tried tls also)
SMTP Username: mygmail@gmail.com
SMTP Password: gmail password
SMTP Port: 465 (tried 587 and 25)
SMTP Timeout: 5

xampp (v 3.2.4) - php.ini (mail function)
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
sendmail_from = mygmail@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"

sendmail.ini

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=ssl
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=mygmail@gmail.com
auth_password=gmail password
pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=
force_sender=mygmail@gmail.com
force_recipient=
hostname=smtp.gmail.com

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: hello @SivaSubramanian A. You can read Documents following URL : https://www.phpflow.com/php/how-to-send-email-from-localhost-using-php/

Comment: Avast Antivirus blocked my SSL port and just removed it. finally, SMTP mail sending working properly.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Opencart you are using ? Did you enabled DisplayUnlockCaptcha from google ?

Comment: Opencart 3.0.3.2 yes enabled DisplayUnlockCaptcha and less secure apps also turned on